# HDFS with Talend

Tags: hadoop, talend

I am trying to put a csv file from my local windows machine to HDFS using Talend 6.3

I have 4 node cluster ( all linux servers from azure):

1 Namenode and 3 Datanodes.

I am getting following error while running:

**"Exception in component tHDFSPut_1
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/root/5/source.csv could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation."**

File is getting created in HDFS but it is empty file.

Note: I am writing my Namenode IP address in **NameNode URL**

I tried same with sandbox. Same error was there.

Update:

I created a complete new cluster(1 namenode and 3 datanodes). Still I am getting same error.

Everything is running and is is in green (in Ambari). and I am able to put file through hadoop fs -put. Might be some problem in talend?

Comment: Based on your update, I would say there must be a problem with Talend (probably with how you configured/how you use it). As such I have removed my answer. -- Just keep in mind that this is such a basic thing, that you either did something strange, or other should have ran into it. Perhaps searching helps, here is something I found that may be relevant: http://carloblogt.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/using-talend-big-data-to-put-files-on.html